# Why is a linear map $L: k^2 \to k^2$ always of the form $L(u,v) = (au+bv, cu+dv)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is a linear map $L: k^2 \to k^2$ always of the form $$L(u,v) = (au+bv, cu+dv),$$
where $a,b,c,d \in k$? I see why the given formula is a linear map, but I want to show that every linear map satisfies that formula. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever the linear map $L$ is, we have that $L(1,0)$ and $L(0,1)$ are elements of $k^2$. Thus,
$$L(1,0)=(a,c),\qquad L(0,1)=(b,d)$$
for some $a,b,c,d\in k$. Because $L$ is linear, we therefore have that
$$\begin{align*}
L(u,v)&=L(u\cdot(1,0)+v\cdot (0,1))\\\\
&=u\cdot L(1,0)+v\cdot L(0,1)\\\\
&=u\cdot(a,c)+v\cdot(b,d)\\\\
&=(au,cu)+(bv,dv)\\\\
&=(au+bv,cu+dv)
\end{align*}$$
for all $(u,v)\in k^2$.